# Bootstrap 4. Плагин: Bootstrap Select. Как сделать так чтоб выпадающее меню было не под select'ом, а на select'е?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4, bootstrap-selectpicker

Вот так как на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выпадающее меню на `select`'е, а не под `select`'ом

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести и что вы хотите получить в результате. Пока что непонятна суть Вашего вопроса. Собственно, его вообще нет.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Имею в виду сделать так чтоб выпадающее меню было не под select'ом, а на select'е

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация на `bootstrap 4`:

```css
.custom{
  top:-41px !important;
  left:-1px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu custom">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если не нужна рамка в фокусе, то убрать её — просто:

```
box-shadow: none; /* Кнопке */
```